# Change the value of a field in one table based off the value of field in a different table in Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a side along inventory system using Access.

I created a transaction table that adds and removes Kits at the point of a deployment. I have another table that has detail information of those kit.

I am trying to update a status field in the details tables when the status of a kit changes in the transaction table.

This is what I have

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command48_Click()
    If Me.KIT_ITEM_Card_Number.Value = [TEST2]![Kit Item Card Number] Then
        [TEST2]![Status] = "Removed"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run an *update query*:

```vb
Private Sub Command48_Click()

    Dim Sql As String

    ' Use one of these:
    ' If value is a number.
    Sql = "Update [TEST2] Set [Status] = 'Removed' Where [Kit Item Card Number] = " & Me!KIT_ITEM_Card_Number.Value & ""
    ' If value is a text.
    Sql = "Update [TEST2] Set [Status] = 'Removed' Where [Kit Item Card Number] = '" & Me!KIT_ITEM_Card_Number.Value & "'"

    CurrentDb.Execute Sql

End Sub
```

And do rename your buttons to something meaningful.